# SQL "Incorrect syntax near '1900-01-01 00:00:00'." when trying to execute a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like below:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[test_stored_procedure]

@id                         nvarchar(20),
@datefm                     datetime,
@dateto                     datetime

as
   ...
end
```

Then I'm trying to call the above stored procedure using below SQL:

```
exec test_stored_procedure @searchKey, cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime), cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime)
```

But when executed, I got the below error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '1900-01-01 00:00:00'.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need use:

```
DECLARE
   @date_start DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
   ,@date_stop DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00';

EXEC test_stored_procedure @searchKey, @date_start, @date_stop;
```

Or:

```
EXEC test_stored_procedure @searchKey, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', '1901-01-01 00:00:00';
```

It is because you cannot use function on parameters with `EXEC` See [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx). You can pass only:

1. value
2. variable
3. DEFAULT

> [ [ @parameter = ] { value | @variable [ OUTPUT ] | [ DEFAULT ]